# WillTerminate Event is never called

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a problem with my iOS Application.

When I kill the app from the iOS Taskbar the `WillTerminate` Event is not called....any ideas why?

The only background service i have setup is the voip SetKeepAliveTimeout Timer (with the "voip" flag in the info.plist). But even if I take this one out the `WillTerminate` event is never fired.

I also register for SignificantLocationChanges on `DidEnterBackground` event.

Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WillTerminate` will not be called on devices and iOS versions supporting multi-tasking (introduced with iOS 4). With iOS 4 the app is only sent to background and if you kill the app from the taskbar, it is actually killed without getting any callback. Still an app can opt-out from the process of being sent to background and then recieve ..terminate events, but also loose its ability to stay loaded in RAM. For opting-out the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` has to be set within `info.plist`.

For a longer explanation check this great article about [iOS 4 Backgrounding and Delegate Messaging](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/)